# Error creating In-Memory Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to create a table, in-memory but it keeps giving me errors like:

> Msg 10794, Level 16, State 85, Line 11 The index option 'pad_index' is
>   not supported with indexes on memory optimized tables.

and another one saying the same thing about Primary Key Clustered.

Those two things above (pad_index and PK Clustered) are needed, unless there is another way to get it to work...

```
[DEMO-Training1] 
GO

/****** Object: Table [dbo].[wtAssetChildren] ******/ 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[wtAssetChildren] ( 
  [wtAssetChildrenID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
  [wtGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, 
  [CallingAssetID] [int] NOT NULL, 
  [AssetID] [int] NOT NULL, 
  [Processed] [bit] NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT [PK_wtAssetChildren] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([wtAssetChildrenID] ASC)
  WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
  ) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[wtAssetChildren] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_wtAssetChildren_Processed] DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Processed] GO
```

Comment: Please post your code, or a simplified version thereof.

Answer (score 0):

In-Memory OLTP Tables have a bunch of restrictions relative to the rest of what generally ships with MS SQL.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246937.aspx for a full list.

Clustered PKs are not supported, for example.  You'll have to use nonclustered primary key indices instead.

Comment: Thanks for that but how would I go about changing this? I'm only a beginner with SQL Server... Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Frankly, if you're new to SQL Server, then I wouldn't recommend trying to implement any kind of in-memory tables in SQL Server.  Just use traditional tables (where you won't be subject to the restrictions that come along with using in-memory tables).  You can use SQL 2014 without using in-memory tables.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how you can create this table in a memory-optimized SQL Server 2014.  Note that just because you can, doesn't mean you should.  You mention you are beginner and memory-optimized tables are more of an advanced option.

```
CREATE DATABASE MemoryOptimizedTest;
GO

ALTER DATABASE MemoryOptimizedTest
    ADD FILEGROUP MemoryOptimizedTest_MemoryOptimized
    CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA;
GO

ALTER DATABASE MemoryOptimizedTest 
    ADD FILE (
          NAME = 'MemoryOptimizedTest__MemoryOptimized1'
        , FILENAME = 'D:\SqlDataFiles\MemoryOptimizedTest__MemoryOptimized1') 
    TO FILEGROUP MemoryOptimizedTest_MemoryOptimized;
GO

ALTER DATABASE MemoryOptimizedTest
    SET MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_ELEVATE_TO_SNAPSHOT=ON;
GO

USE MemoryOptimizedTest;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[wtAssetChildren](
       [wtAssetChildrenID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
     , [wtGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
     , [CallingAssetID] [int] NOT NULL
     , [AssetID] [int] NOT NULL
     , [Processed] [bit] NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [DF_wtAssetChildren_Processed] DEFAULT ((0))
     , CONSTRAINT [PK_wtAssetChildren] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED( [wtAssetChildrenID] ASC )
     )
WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED=ON, DURABILITY=SCHEMA_AND_DATA);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, luckily I work with more experienced SQL nerds and they are helping me with the little things that Im not sure about. However, I am testing SQL 2014 in memory for them so they don't know much about this topic... Thanks again for the help :D much appreciated

Comment: @Tyler, I added the needed `CREATE DATABASE` and `ALTER DATABASE` statements to my answer to help get you started.

Comment: Thankyou for the help :D... I have set this and got one of the other guys to test it on our software, he gets the following error;  Distributed Queries and Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) are not supported with memory optimized tables.

Comment: @Tyler, as we've mentioned here, there are many restrictions for using memory-optimized tables.  Some will require schema and/or application changes so it might not be an option.  In-memory tables may be a solution for a problem you don't have so I suggest you think about what you are trying to accomplish before going through the implementation effort.